# Merging spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have three Google spreadsheets that I want to merge into a master spreadsheet, so that each new entry in any one of the three spreadsheets will automatically update the master.

How can I do that using Google functions?

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the function called `ImportRange` https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093340

All you have to do is make the master spreadsheet pull data from the other spreadsheets using their respective `spreadsheet_keys`. The master spreadsheet will respond to updates on the sections of sheets you decide to include.